# Is there an HtmlUnitDriver for .NET?

Tags: .net, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm using [Selenium's WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) to run some [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) tests for an ASP.NET MVC app I'm working on for self-education.

Using `FirefoxDriver`, `ChromeDriver`, etc. all take so long to run, it's actually pretty frustrating to use them (in my opinion).

I have read about an [`HtmlUnitDriver`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#htmlunit-driver) that is supposedly much faster than the browser-based drivers; but I can't seem to find a version in the .NET client library (only Java). Is there a .NET version out there?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To use HtmlUnit you need to use the RemoteWebDriver and pass in the desired capabilities for it.

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit())
```

and away you go. If you want the Firefox implementation to run use

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript())
```

Comment: MUCH faster than the other drivers, and perfect for simple HTML tests. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget this means you need to start the Selenium-Server-Standalone.jar on the machine you want to run the browser

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work... 13:29:08.259 INFO - WebDriver remote server: Executing: [new session: null] at U
RL: /session)
13:29:08.269 INFO - WebDriver remote server: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerExc
eption

Comment: Didn't work for me using Selenium 2.53.1:
`The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=htmlunit, version=, platform=ANY}]`

Answer (score 2):

The RemoteWebDriver approach is the one the Selenium devs recommend: [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/34b66b72dd480b7d?pli=1)

As per that link however, if you prefer, it is easy enough invoke HtmlUnit via **IKVM**; that worked well for me.

I think Steve Sanderson [described this first](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the answer right now is unfortunately **no**. I found this on the [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) site; a user asked:

> Is this possible to transfer to C#?

...to which one of the developers responded:

> Not without taking a dependency on IKVM, which is not something we are prepared to do at this time.

Oh well :(

Comment: The other reason is there isnt a decent enough .NET JavaScript engine where Java has a few...

Comment: Does the selected answer is the answer or the ultimate answer is no ?!?!