# How to access HtmlUnit specific functionality if using RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: .net, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

As mentiond at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094605/is-there-an-htmlunitdriver-for-net) that we have to have use RemoteWebDriver to use HtmlUnitDriver on .Net environment. Using RemoteWebDriver I can only use IWebDriver specific functions. But I would like to access some functions implemented by HtmlUnitDriver (i.e. getWebClient()) to be able to use all the advanced functionality of HtmlUnit. How can I do that?

Specifically what I want to achieve for example is to set Locale of HtmlUnit on HtmlUnitDriver and that requires that I set HTTP headers in HtmlUnit but RemoteWebDriver would not allow me to do that. Any ideas?