# Selenium .NET HtmlUnitDriver failed to connect to remote server

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm porting some Selenium JUnit tests to a .NET project (tests for a MVC project).

I have following line in Java:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

I ported it to .NET like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
```

In Java this works perfectly to test a Spring application, but in .NET it throws an Exception:

```
Test method TDD.Tests.Acceptatie.TestLoginScreen.LoginScreenTest threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error.       
System.Net.WebException: Can't connect to remote server  --->     
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
Can't connect because target computer actively refused the connection 127.0.0.1:4444
```

NOTE: the error message is translated from dutch so probably not the exact message in english.

I have added the Selenium.Webdriver NuGet package. The project structure is the following:

- MVC-project (TDD)
- NUnit project (TDD.Tests) with a ref to TDD

The MVC project is configured to run on localhost:8080 and I also tried to set the webdriver to that ip:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:8080"), DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
```

I also tried to use the loopback address instead of 'localhost'.

Versions:
[image: Versions]

Anyone knows what could cause this problem and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Binary versions please

Comment: Added to question (if that's what you meant?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to invoke the [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver.htm) Class is as follows:

```
public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)

where:
remoteAddress
    Type: System.Uri
    URI containing the address of the WebDriver remote server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub).

desiredCapabilities
    Type: OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities
    An ICapabilities object containing the desired capabilities of the browser.
```

As per the error...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error.       
System.Net.WebException: Can't connect to remote server  --->     
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
Can't connect because target computer actively refused the connection 127.0.0.1:4444
```

It seems your program/script is unable to connect to the *WebDriver Remote Server*.

As per your second code trial **http://localhost:8080** is your *Application Server* but not the *WebDriver Remote Server* e.g. `Selenium Grid Hub`. Hence your program show the error. If you are using *Selenium Grid* change the line as:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
```

---

Finally, a quick look at the *API Docs* of *Inheritance Hierarchy* of [OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver.htm) shows the following hierarchy where `HtmlUnit` is **not present**:

[image: OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver]

---

However as per the discussion [Is there an HtmlUnitDriver for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094605/is-there-an-htmlunitdriver-for-net) your first code trial should have worked:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
```

If you want to use the *Firefox Implementation* you can:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript());
```

---

### TL;DR

- [HtmlUnit wrapper for .NET (2.0b3)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/NLZrct1IC30)
- [Using HtmlUnit on .NET for Headless Browser Automation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/)