# Selenium WebDriverWait class unusable when adding Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nuget

I am trying to use Selenium's  WebDriverWait together with Selenium PhantomJSDriver in my test .
At the addition of the Selenium.WebDriver package, the class is usable ( under OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI)
When I add the Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform package, that becomes unusable.

If I switch the order of adding the above mentioned packages( managed both time via Nuget, using Rider), the Selenium.WebDriver will make the OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS unreachable . 
I have also added Selenium.Support as seen  here : [Cannot find WebDriverWait class in OpenQA.Selenium (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651528/cannot-find-webdriverwait-class-in-openqa-selenium-c/32651529#comment102487625_32651529), but that did not help.

Any suggestions on how could I use the WebDriverWait together with PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is deprecated for several years. Use headless chrome instead

```
ChromeOptions options = .ChromeOptions()
options.AddArguments("headless");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options));
```

Comment: I was interested in PhantomJS because it did not imply having a browser installed. As far as I know, using ChromeDriver does require having Chrome browser installed, which is kind of a deal-breaker because I would want to run it on a machine which won't have it.
Does it happen to know an alternative for that in Selenium?

Comment: @Daniel Have a look at [HtmlUnitDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094605/is-there-an-htmlunitdriver-for-net)

Comment: Thank you, I will check out that first ( also maybe selenium xvfb) . I will accept this as answer as it puts me on the right track.